# Weird result of 'optimizing' indices of a SQL Server database, what's the reason?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, size

I stumbled across a log database which is designed to keep the data of the past 60 days and provide indices, that enable fast data analysis.

The database consisted of 26GB data space and 10GB index storage and after analyzing the indices I figured, that ~50 percent are never used or simply inefficient, so I set up to perform the following change:

**OLD**

```
IX                                        MODE                 SIZE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK_PerformanceData                        CLUSTERED            26,09 GB
IX_PerformanceData_Controller             NON_CLUSTERED         2,07 GB
IX_PerformanceData_AppName                NON_CLUSTERED         1,89 GB
IX_PerformanceData_ControllerMethod       NON_CLUSTERED         1,73 GB
IX_PerformanceData_StartTime              NON_CLUSTERED         1,35 GB
IX_PerformanceData_AppHost                NON_CLUSTERED         1,30 GB
IX_PerformanceData_LogTime                NON_CLUSTERED         0,79 GB
IX_PerformanceData_StatusCode             NON_CLUSTERED         0,57 GB
IX_PerformanceData_ProcessException       NON_CLUSTERED         0,54 GB
```

**NEW**

```
IX                                       MODE             SIZE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CIX_PerformanceData_AppName_Controller   CLUSTERED        26,99 GB
IX_PerformanceData_LogTime               NON-CLUSTERED     3,62 GB
IX_PerformanceData_ProvId                NON-CLUSTERED     3,61 GB
PK_PerformanceData                       NON-CLUSTERED     3,57 GB
IX_PerformanceData_ProcessException      NON-CLUSTERED     3,34 GB
```

Columns:

```
VARCHAR(n) = Controller, AppName, ControllerMethod, AppHost
DATETIME = StartTime, LogTime
SMALLINT = StatusCode
BIGINT = Id, ProvId
BIT = ProcessException
```

I changed the string typed indices to a single CLUSTERED one (~20 variations possible), as I thought this would result in a nice and dandy small B-TREE index. Furthermore I removed some of the indices that didn't had any usage regarding the journal.

Before the index storage was already about 40 percent of the data volume and I suspected it to drop below 10 percent. Unfortunately they become unreasonably big and it looks like every index points to the clustered string literal and thus jumping to about 52 percent of the data space.

Even the clustered index works much faster now the space consumption is quite rubbish. Can anybody explain this observation and is there any best practice to solve my problem?

Comment: thanks for the formatting Marc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a clustered index, this becomes the pointer at the leaf node of all indexes referencing said table.  This can help performance in that if the data you are retrieving is stored in the clustered index you do not need to actually go to the table to get it.

The best practice depends on what you want.  Indexes improve read performance at the cost of disk space.  As you start to build indexes that contain data, like a covered index using include, the amount of storage goes up dramatically along with performance on reads. I believe indexes always slow writing, I could be wrong though.

In my opinion the best practice is to find the balance that suits your requirements and budget.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Basically the requirements are met and the disk quota is not an issue. It's just that this result seems totally counter intuitive and inefficient. The target I aimed for is a dictionary-like index on the literal fields and efficient sized numeric/date indices.

Do you know how the server handles the situation, if I have no clustered index set at all?

Comment: It depends on your queries.  I find this article covers the topic very well.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/

Comment: Thanks for the information, it got me to a more in-depth understanding of the matter and my actual problem. I rebuild the structure again and the index space is down to 4GB with equivalent performance to the prior setup.